# what's the best way to check if an object's attribute is empty?

Tags: java

For example, I use `StringUtils.isEmpty(Object.attribute);` to check if an attribute is empty. Should I put that code everytime I need to check if this attribute is empty. Or is it better to wrap it in a method `Object.isAttributeEmpty()` then call the `StringUtils.isEmpty()` inside `isAttributeEmpty()`.

Which way is the best practice or preferred way.

Comment: What is an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "attribute being empty" has special significance, then you're better off creating a boolean getter to name it and have as its implementation to call to the utility method:

```
class MyClass {
    String attribute;
    boolean isIncomplete() {
        return isEmpty(attribute);
   }
   // other stuff
}
```

there is also the opportunity to name it in the opposite sense, eg taking my example above:

```
boolean isComplete() {
    return !isEmpty(attribute);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can really be a matter of style, and the rest is up to having a little vigilance in the code right before either of these is called to make sure that Object itself isn't null.

Personally I've done ways where I would write a static method in a Utility class that would then provide a method like ObjectUtility.isAttributeEmpty(Object object) and let the black box internals figure it out safely.

And at other times, it can be comfortable to have the object itself know.  It depends on if the style dictates that you should be writing simple Java objects or if you allow for more complex methods to be inherent in the objects.

The even worse question becomes how do you answer a true/false question when the third answer is "it's null".